# SQL query not returning the right results - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables :

Charge_volume:

```
cust_sign_month      month      months_since_cust      country      Charge_volume
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01              2018-01        1                      DE           100
2018-01              2018-02        1                      DE           100
2018-01              2018-03        1                      DE           100
2019-01              2019-01        1                      IN           100
2019-02              2019-02        1                      IN           1,000
2019-03              2019-03        1                      IN           1,000
2019-04              2019-04        1                      IN           1,000
```

`Active_Customers`:

```
    cust_sign_month      month      months_since_cust      country      perc_active_cust
    2018-01              2018-01        1                      DE           72%
    2018-01              2018-02        1                      DE           71%
    2018-01              2018-03        1                      DE           69%
    2019-01              2019-01        1                      IN           72%
    2019-02              2019-02        1                      IN           71%
    2019-03              2019-03        1                      IN           80%
    2019-04              2019-04        1                      IN           90%
```

`New_customers`:

```
     month          country      new_cust_onboarded
     -----------------------------------------------
     2018-01             DE           40,000
     2018-02             DE           41,000
     2018-03             DE           42,000
     2019-01             IN           43,000
     2019-02             IN           30,000
     2019-03             IN           21,000
     2019-04             IN           12,000
```

JOIN conditions: `Active_customers` and `New_Customers` will be joined on `cust_sign_month` and month respectively. And `Charge_volume` and `Active_customers` will be joined on all common keys that there in both the tables

My question is that I need to fetch the total charge volume in 2019 ordered by the months starting from 2019-01 to 2019-04.

The output should look like this :

```
Activity_Month        Total_transactions_2019
---------------------------------------------
2019-01                 309600
2019-02               23430000
2019-03               18480000
2019-04               11880000
```

I have written the below query but it is not returning any results and I am getting an error

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous column name: month)

My query:

```
SELECT 
    a.month AS Activity_Month,
    SUM(REPLACE(a.Charge_volume, ',', '') * (REPLACE(c.new_cust_onboarded , ',', '') * b.perc_active_cust) AS Total_transactions_2019
FROM 
    Charge_volume a 
JOIN 
    Active_Customers b 
JOIN 
    New_customers c ON a.cust_sign_month = b.cust_sign_month
                    AND a.country = b.country
                    AND a.month = b.month
                    AND a.months_since_cust = b.months_since_cust
                    AND b.cust_sign_month = c.month    
                    AND b.country = c.country 
                    AND substring(a.month, 1, 4) = '2019'
GROUP BY 
    month
ORDER BY 
    month
```

Comment: "SQL query not returning the right results" is a weird title for a query not returning any results at all because of a syntax error. A much more appropriate title would have been "Can't resolve [SQLITE_ERROR] ambiguous column name" for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your corrected and working SQL query. But the expression in the `SUM` function does not give the expected result. Perhaps you need to divide the values of the `perc_active_cust` column by 100.

```
SELECT 
    a.month AS Activity_Month,
    SUM(
      REPLACE(a.Charge_volume, ',', '') * 
      REPLACE(c.new_cust_onboarded , ',', '') * (b.perc_active_cust / 100)
    ) AS Total_transactions_2019
FROM Charge_volume a 
JOIN Active_Customers b 
     ON a.cust_sign_month = b.cust_sign_month 
    AND a.country = b.country 
    AND a.month = b.month 
    AND a.months_since_cust = b.months_since_cust
JOIN New_customers c 
     ON b.cust_sign_month = c.month    
    AND b.country = c.country 
WHERE a.month BETWEEN '2019-01' AND '2019-04'
GROUP BY a.month
ORDER BY a.month
```

Note that the `substring` function does not exist in SQLite.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYrN4LFoDqdN4Ck1oTHuN7/0)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to specify your table alias in your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
GROUP BY a.month
ORDER BY a.month
```

That is the only place in your query where I see `month` used without specifying a table alias to disambiguate it.